# Futur 2 mit Konjunktiv 2 Beispiel

Tags: subjunctive, future

Ich bin mir bei folgendem Satz unsicher:

> Aber nicht dass du dich später beschwerst, weil das Meeting nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich gewesen wird sein könnte: [...]

Es hört sich, wenn ich es laut lese, merkwürdig an. Ich tue mir aber schwer, eine bessere bzw. die richtige Konstruktion zu finden. Ich denke mal, dass hier Futur 2 und Konjunktiv 2 involviert sind. Wenn ich "Das Meeting wird X gewesen sein." und "Das Meeting könnte X sein." kombiniere, folge ich "Das Meeting könnte X gewesen sein werden." oder "Das Meeting wird X gewesen sein können". Das Erstere klingt komisch und das Zweitere klingt nicht mehr nach dem, was ich sagen will. Ich will ja ausdrücken, dass etwas in Zukunft gewesen sein könnte (oder könnte gewesen sein werden), also sage ich "wird gewesen sein könnte" ... und das Rumprobieren geht weiter. Kann mir jemand helfen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rein grammatisch gesehen hat Björn Friedrich die Frage schon beantwortet:

> …, weil das Meeting nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich gewesen sein können wird.

Inhaltlich ist das aber nicht richtig, weil die Möglichkeit, die "könnte" ausdrückt, ja nur in der Gegenwart eine Möglichkeit ist. Wenn das Meeting vorbei ist - das ist die Zeitebene des Nebensatzes -, ist es mit der Möglichkeit vorbei, dann hat sich bereits herausgestellt, ob das Meeting relevant war oder nicht. Das gilt erst recht, wenn sich die andere Person beschwert, also noch später.

Deshalb hat "könnte" in dem Nebensatz inhaltlich gar nichts mehr zu suchen.

Das Futur II zu benutzen, ist auch grammatisch letztlich falsch, weil der übergeordnete Satz im Präsens steht ("nicht dass du dich beschwerst"). Das Futur wird durch das Wort "später" auch genügend ausgedrückt. Im Nebensatz reicht dann eine normale Vergangenheitsform, die als relativ zu "später" verstanden wird.

> Aber nicht dass du dich später beschwerst, wenn das Meeting nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich war.

Wenn man unbedingt ein Futur II benutzen möchte:

> Du wirst dich womöglich später beschweren, wenn das Meeting nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich gewesen sein wird.

Das klingt allerdings sehr gestelzt.

"Könnte" ist, wie gesagt, nur in einer Zeitebene vor dem Ende des Meetings und vor dem Beschwerenn sinnvoll. Deshalb wird die Kombination mit dem Futur II in einem Satz schon schwierig. Z.B.

> Es könnte sein, du dich darüber beschweren wirst, dass das Meeting nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich gewesen sein wird.

Die (möglicherweise denkbare) kürzere Form eines abhängigen Futur gibt es nicht: <s>"du könntest dich später beschweren werden"</s>. Da reicht dann einfach das Präsens: "du könntest dich später beschweren".

Answer (score 2):

Der grammatikalisch korrekte Ausdruck lautet *etwas wird gewesen sein können*, nicht *könnte*. (Zur inhaltlichen Sinnhaftigkeit oder stilistischen Eleganz in dem konkreten Beispiel siehe die anderen Antworten.)

Da in einem Nebensatz das finite Verb, hier *wird*, am Ende steht, müssen wir den Beispielsatz noch etwas umsortieren:

> …, weil das Meeting nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich *gewesen sein können wird*.

In einem (mittlerweile gelöschten) Kommentar wurde darum gebeten, diesen Nebensatz in einen Hauptsatz umzuformen. Das sieht dann so aus:

> Das Meeting *wird* nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich *gewesen sein können*.

Comment: "wird gewesen sein könnte" ist eindeutig falsch, schon deswegen, weil dort zwei finite Verbformen vorkommen. aber auf "gewesen sein können" ist nicht wirklich gutes Deutsch.

Answer (score 1):

Mein Sprachgefühl sagt, der einfachste (und natürlichste?) Weg diesen Sachverhalt auszudrücken wäre

> Aber nicht, dass du dich später beschwerst, dass das Meeting nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich (gewesen) war/wäre.

Answer (score 0):

Ich frage mich erst einmal, was der Sinn der Übung ist. Konjunktiv II Futur II ist einfach die Ersatzform für den Konjunktiv II Perfekt. So wie Konjunktiv II Futur I die Ersatzform für Konjunktiv II ist.

> Das gilt, falls er es verstünde. — Konjunktiv II

> Das gilt, falls er es verstehen würde. — Konjunktiv II Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II Futur I)

> Das gilt, falls er es verstanden hätte. — Konjunktiv II Perfekt

> Das gilt, falls er es verstanden haben würde. — Konjunktiv II Perfekt Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II Futur II)

---

Nun hast du zusätzlich ein Modalverb reingemischt. Dadurch wird das Partizip II in den Perfekt-Varianten zum Infinitiv, und das Modalverb steht im Ersatzinfinitiv. Außerdem muss *haben* die Reihe der Infinitive anführen. Das ist eine Sonderregel für diesen Fall.

> Das gilt, falls er es verstehen könnte. — Konjunktiv II

> Das gilt, falls er es verstehen können würde. — Konjunktiv II Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II Futur I)

> Das gilt, falls er es hätte verstehen können. — Konjunktiv II Perfekt

> Das gilt, falls er es haben verstehen können würde. — Konjunktiv II Perfekt Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II Futur II)

Außerdem darf man *werden* hier auch an den Anfang der Reihe setzen. Das klingt sogar besser.

> Das gilt, falls er es würde verstehen können. — Konjunktiv II Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II Futur I) mit führendem *werden.*

> Das gilt, falls er es würde haben verstehen können. — Konjunktiv II Perfekt Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II Futur II) mit führendem *werden.*

---

Als letzte Komplikation verwendest du *sein* als Vollverb.

> Das gilt, falls es sein könnte. — Konjunktiv II

> Das gilt, falls es sein können würde. — Konjunktiv II Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II Futur I)

> Das gilt, falls es hätte sein können. — Konjunktiv II Perfekt

> Das gilt, falls es haben sein können würde. — Konjunktiv II Perfekt Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II Futur II)

Wieder die alternative Reihenfolgen:

> Das gilt, falls es würde sein können. — Konjunktiv II Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II Futur I) mit führendem *werden.*

> Das gilt, falls es würde haben sein können. — Konjunktiv II Perfekt Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II Futur II) mit führendem *werden.*

---

Im Ergebnis:

> Aber nicht dass du dich später beschwerst, weil das Meeting nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich haben sein können würde.

oder

> Aber nicht dass du dich später beschwerst, weil das Meeting nicht so
> wahnsinnig relevant für dich würde haben sein können.

oder, ohne die Ersatzform zu bemühen:

> Aber nicht dass du dich später beschwerst, weil das Meeting nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich **hätte sein können.**

Diese Form solltest du bevorzugen. Für *haben* benötigt man die Ersatzform nicht.

Außerdem scheint mir die ganze Formulierung mit dem Modalverb fragwürdig. Besser:

> Aber nicht dass du dich später beschwerst, weil das Meeting nicht so wahnsinnig relevant für dich **gewesen wäre.**